# When to omit "to" with infinitives

Tags: complementation, bare-infinitives

I want you **to** feel better
I want you  feel better

That was the right thing **to** do
That was the right thing  do

when somebody challenges you **to** dance
when somebody challenges you  dance

I'm not telling you **to** go around
I'm not telling you  go around

you are trying  **to** make us not practice
you are trying   make us not practice

just try **to**  relax and breath
just try   relax and breath

What does ***to*** point to in the sentences? Is it OK if I remove **to** in the above sentences?

Comment: You must use *to* in all of these sentences. I'll leave a more in-depth answer to someone else, but none of these sentences are correct without *to*.

Comment: @Wendi is right. The only exception I can think of – and this is a strectch – is the one with _telling_, and, even then, omitting the _to_ requires a punctuation change: _I'm not telling you, "Go around."_ In other words, if you put the message in quotation marks, you can omit the _to_.

Answer (score 5):

There are only a few verbs which permit the bare infinitive (unmarked with *to*) in complementary non-finite clauses. These fall mostly into two classes (I’ve marked the absence of *to* with the conventional null symbol Ø):

- ***causatives*** - *have*, *help*, *let*, *make*

  > I’ll have my assistant Ø send you the forms.
  >   She helped him Ø correct his paper.
  >   We cannot let this Ø happen.
  >   The Devil made me Ø do it.
- ***perceptives*** - *feel*, *hear*, *see* and others

  > He felt the wind Ø pick up.
  >   I heard you Ø say it.
  >   A witness saw him Ø shoot the deceased.

But most verbs, and all of those in your examples, require the marked infinitive (*to*-infinitive) in complementary clauses. (However, the *to* may be omitted by ellipsis when two or more infinitives are aligned in parallel, as in your last example: *Just try **to** relax and Ø breathe.* Here the *to* is implied before *breathe*, but need not be explicit.)

The bare infinitive is also used in questions with *Why*, with the full modal auxiliaries *can/could*, *do/did*, *may/might*, *must*, *shall/should*, *will/would*, and sometimes with the semi-modals *dare* and *need*.

Comment: It would be great if you appended some examples after the last explanation concerning the `questions with why`.